# Is there a way to auto resume an incomplete job after sql server restart?

Tags: sql-server

I ran into problem of job stopped after the sql server restart.

Is there a way to auto resume an incomplete job after sql server restart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell maybe. If you have a sql job without a notion of persistence then no:( The job will continue to run according to schedule but it will not pick up from an earlier starting point unless you have to logic to do so.

Comment: ltn, can you suggest a logic to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are doing batch work then you can store links to records already processed or save state of what has been done in a table. Make yours job only work against data that has not been marked as processed. That way it does not matter when the job is queued.